# How to convert XML to Object using JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey, dropwizard

My client is using DropWizard/Jersey.

I am getting a response back in the form of xml. It looks like this:

[image]

I've created a file called `package-info.java` with following contents:

```
@XmlSchema(
        namespace = "http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01",
        elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)

package com.aerstone.services.core.handlerpojos.amazon;


import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

Finally, I have a POJO which looks like this. For now I'm just trying to map the title and ASIN.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="ItemSearchResponse")
public class AmazonItem
{
    private String name;
    private String asin;

    public AmazonItem(){}

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
    @XmlElement(name="Title")
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){this.name = name;}

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
    @XmlElement(name="ASIN")
    public String getAsin(){ return asin;}

    public void setAsin(String asin){ this.asin = asin; }
}
```

I'm using it like this:

```
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(AmazonItem.class);
        Unmarshaller unMarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
        newItem = (AmazonItem) unMarshaller.unmarshal(response);
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
! javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"ItemLookupResponse"). Expected elements are <{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}ItemSearchResponse>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to unmarshal a document that starts with:

```
<ItemLookupRespons>
```

Instead of the XML document you have in your question that starts with:

```
<ItemSearchResponse xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01">
```

If you created your JAXB model from an XML schema where the document you are trying to unmarshal is valid then you should create your `JAXBContext` on the package name of the generated model, or on the `ObjectFactory` class that was generated to pull in all the classes for the model.